# Styling country names on a Google maps with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary

I want to style country names on a Google map. I use this code :

```
var styles = [
    {
        featureType: "administrative.country",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [ { color: '#f24547' } ]
    }
];

map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: navigationData.googlePosition,
    zoom: 15 
});
map.setOptions( { styles: styles } );
```

It's work but the result is :

[image]

I don't arrive to remove the shadow arround the country names. You have an idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `elementType: 'labels.text.fill',` in style

```
var styles = [
    {
    featureType: 'administrative.country',
    elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
    stylers: [{color: '#f24547'}]
    }
];
```

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/swmshcLf/2/) for demo, from [google map guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)

Comment: It's run fine. Thanks a lot.